# Load next post by ID on a single page

Tags: shortcode, ajax, single, infinite-scroll

I hope this topic is not duplicated. I see some similar topics but non of them can solve my problem, so I decided to put a new one.

Here's the case.
I have a single.php post with the defualt wordpress comments template... So when I click the button I'm loading the next post, very easy with json, beneath the current post(something like infinite scroll). The problem is that shortcodes are not rendering from json and comments template as well.
I'm using Crayon code highlighter plugin, and when open a post on single page it renders but when loaded with json, no.

Here's a bit of my code so you can get the idea:

**functions.php**

```
function renderArticle($pid) {
    //apply_filters($post) = do_shortcode($post);
    ob_start();
    $post = get_post($pid);
    ?>
    <article class="article" data-id="<?php print $post->ID ?>" data-url="<?php print the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="title"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_title) ?></div>
        <div class="content"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content) ?></div>
        <div class="post-date"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_date) ?></div>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </article>
    <?php
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    vd($data);
    $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print $json;
}
function parameter_queryvars_pid($qvars) {

    $qvars[] = 'pid';
    return $qvars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars_pid');
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {

    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        if ($wp->request == 'next-post') {
            if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['pid'])) {
                $pid = $wp_query->query_vars['pid'];
                renderArticle($pid);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**load.js**

```
$("button#load").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.location.origin + "/next-post",
        data: {
            pid: 120
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("body").append($(data));
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert("Oooooppps. Try again.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**single.php**

```
<div class="post-listing">
    <article class="article" data-id="<?php print $post->ID ?>" data-url="<?php print the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="title"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_title) ?></div>
        <div class="content"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content) ?></div>
        <div class="post-date"><?php print apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_date) ?></div>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </article>
</div>
<button id="load">Load more</button>
```

This is pretty much. If I'm missing some resources, please let me know and I will provide.

I hope you guys can help me with that.

Cheers

Comment: if you need create ajax in WordPress especially for single post, use admin-ajax.php take a look this tutorial https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found a solution to this and it is pretty easy. So I'm gonna post all the code for future uses:

**single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$post = get_post();
$post_cat = get_the_category($post);
$data = collection_data_json($post_cat[0]->term_id, $post->ID);
$data_details = collection_order_permalink($data);
$author_id = intval($post->post_author);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cat = "<?php print $post_cat_id ?>";
    var pid = "<?php print $post->ID ?>";
    var post_details = <?php print $data ?>;
    var post_order = <?php print $data_details ?>;

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/lib/js/single-post.js"></script>
<div class="entries" id="entries">
    <article class="article" data-url="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" data-id="<?php print $post->ID ?>">
        <h1 class="start-indicator"><?php print $post->post_title ?></h1>
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="time"><?php print $post->post_date ?></span>
            <span class="category"><?php print $post_cat[0]->name ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="category-mobile"><?php print $post_cat[0]->name ?></div>    
        <div class="meta meta-mobile">By <a href="<?php print get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>"><?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?></a>, <?php print the_author_meta("job_position", $author_id); ?> at WePay | <?php print $post->post_date ?></div>
        <div class="speed-reading">
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/speed-reading-black.png" alt="Estimated reading time">
            <span><?php print reading_time($post->post_content, intval(get_option("reading_time"))) ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="post-by">
                <figure>
                    <img src="<?php print get_avatar_url($author_id); ?>" alt="<?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>" title="<?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>">
                    <figcaption>By <a href="<?php print get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" title="<?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>"><?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?></a>, <?php print the_author_meta("job_position", $author_id); ?> at WePay</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <?php print apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- End -->
        <div class="author">
            <a href="<?php print get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>"> - <?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="about-author">
            <h3><span>About the author</span></h3>
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="<?php print get_avatar_url($author_id); ?>" alt="<?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="position"><a href="<?php print get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" title="<?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>"><?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?></a>, <?php print the_author_meta("job_position", $author_id); ?> at WePay</p>
                <p class="bio"><?php print the_author_meta("description", $author_id) ?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php print get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" class="more" title="More blog posts by <?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?>">More blog posts by <?php print get_userdata($author_id)->display_name ?></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article-social">
            <h4>Follow us on</h4>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="http://twitter.com" class="t" title="Follow us on Twitter"></a>
                <a href="http://facebook.com" class="f" title="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
                <a href="http://linkedin.com" class="l" title="Find us on Linkedin"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php comments_template() ?>
    </article>
</div>

<!-- Social Icons -->
<div class="share-post">
    <div class="share-on-twitter">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php print get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="Share this post on Twitter">
            <span class="shares"></span>
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/t.png" alt="Twitter" class="hover">
        </a>    
    </div>
    <div class="share-on-facebook">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="Share this post on Facebook">
            <span class="shares"></span>
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/f.png" alt="Faceook" class="hover">
        </a>    
    </div>
    <div class="share-on-linkedin">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="Share this post on Linkedin">
            <span class="shares"></span>
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin">
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/l.png" alt="Linkedin" class="hover">
        </a>    
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**single-post.js**

```
var pc = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    post_order = formatCollection(post_order);
    post_details = formatCollection(post_details);

    function formatCollection(objCollection) {
        var items = {};
        var i = 0;
        for (var index in objCollection) {
            items[i] = objCollection[index];
            i++;
        }
        return items;
    }

    function set_first_url() {
        $("body").append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("id", "url-identifier").attr("data-url", post_order[pc]));
    }
    set_first_url();

    function set_next_url(position) {
        if (pc >= Object.keys(post_order).length) {
            console.log("no posts left");
            remove_url_identifier();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("body").find("#url-identifier").detach();
            $("body").append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("id", "url-identifier").attr("data-url", post_order[position]));
        }
    }

    function append_next_article(article) {
        $("div#entries").append(article);
    }

    function remove_url_identifier() {
        $("body").find("#url-identifier").detach();
    }

    function crawl_url(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                var article = $(data).find("div#entries article.article");
                append_next_article(article);
                pc++;
                set_next_url(pc);          
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert("Oooooppps. Something happened. Don't tell my boss !");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).scroll(function (e) {
        if (processing)
            return false;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
            processing = true;
            var next_url = $("body").find("#url-identifier").data("url");
            if (typeof next_url === "undefined")
                return false;
            crawl_url(next_url);

            unique = [];
            processing = false;
        }
    }); 
});
```

**single-next.php**

```
function collection_order_permalink($collection) {
    $collection = json_decode($collection);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($collection); $i++) {
        $collection[$i] = get_permalink($collection[$i]->ID);
    }
    return json_encode($collection, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

function sort_collection_data($collection, $arrkey) {

    $result = [];
    $result[0] = $collection[$arrkey];
    for ($i = 0, $t = 1; $i < count($collection) - 1; $i++, $t++) {
        if ($i == $arrkey) {
            $t -= 1;
            continue;
        }
        $result[$t] = $collection[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}

function collection_data_json($cat, $pid = null) {
    $args = ['post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 999999, 'cat' => $cat, 'orderby' => "date"];
    $allCategoryPosts = new WP_Query($args);
    $allCategoryPosts = $allCategoryPosts->posts; // Collection with the original post order
    $multikey = multidimensional_search($allCategoryPosts, $pid);
    $ordered = "";
    if ($multikey !== false) {
        $ordered = sort_collection_data($allCategoryPosts, $multikey);
        $ordered = filter_date($ordered);
        $ordered = filter_permalink($ordered);
        $ordered = filter_author($ordered);
    }
    return json_encode($ordered, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Comment: this implementation is probably too naive. If I got it right you load twice the header and footer, and you will probably execute some JS again (which might be good or bad). General strategy for infi scroll should be to get the data that you need, which most likely is less then the whole page

Comment: What I do is requesting the url, and when I receive the HTML from the whole page in the Ajax response, I find only the article that I need, make it obj and append it to the container of my current page, so all the short codes are rendered. If think this is a bad approach, let me know why and down vote it. (: Cheers.

Comment: ha ok, missed that.